# iOS app going to sleep after 1 minute of communication with Watch - WatchKit

Tags: ios, swift, background, watchkit, watchos-2

I'm implementing simple one-line communication between iOS app and watchKit with sendMessage.

The issue is - the communication is continuous.
The user presses a button on appleWatch, same action happens on Phone e.t.c.
Unfortunately, after two or three actions - the iOS app stops responding.
As advised by some on the forums - i've implemented `backgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`, however, it doesn't work (doesn't give me even a promised three minute timeout).

Here's my code in the iOS app AppDelegate

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject]) {
        //recieve messages from watch
        print(message["b"]! as? String)
        let sweetN = message["b"]! as? String
        //var sweetB = message["abs"]! as? [Int : Bool]
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            let taskID = self.beginBackgroundUpdateTask()
            if sweetN == "peeks"{
                if WCSession.isSupported(){
                    let message = [ "gettingData": "datareceived" ]
                    session.sendMessage(message, replyHandler: { replyDict in }, errorHandler: { error in })
                }
            }
            self.endBackgroundUpdateTask(taskID)
        })
    }
    func beginBackgroundUpdateTask() -> UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier {
        return UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({})
    }
    func endBackgroundUpdateTask(taskID: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(taskID)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
You have to set the WCSession in the app delegate like:

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

```
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()
    }

func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {
    replyHandler(["message": "received!"])
}
```

and in the apple watch: the file extension delegate.swift do the same:

```
override init() {

    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()
    }
}
```